# MVC practices through Node?

Tags: node.js

I'm a front-end developer with a desire to learn more on functional programming and template engine processing through JavaScrit.

I'm currently learning the [Node](https://nodejs.org/en/) platform, which I initiate through Visual Studio Code terminal to build custom JavaScript apps.  But I want to take Node further.  Does Node provide any good resources on building an MVC (Model View Controller) like applications?

Just to give a little background, I just finished a course in MVC 5 for ASP.NET (which I really enjoyed through Visual Studio 2017), but would like something similar to that which is JavaScript based.

Thanks for any recommended resources!  I want to make sure what I am diving into gives me the end goal I am looking for.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On top of node.js you can use different frameworks, one of the most important is [express](http://expressjs.com/) but there are many others, look at [nodeframework](http://nodeframework.com/).

Then I suggest to use some best practices. Personally I've found really useful the following for express:
https://github.com/i0natan/nodebestpractices#1-project-structure-practices